# HasGroup = true appearing in jwt token claims but roles values are not appearing

Tags: angular, azure, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I had added group claims in token configuration (Azure Ad app). I am getting a value hasGroup: true in my token but not getting group list in it.
Please help.

```
 "claims": {
      "aud": "a9c3b904-326c-4bee-bd6b-96fac74d8ede",
      "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/..../v2.0",
      "iat": 1613638734,
      "nbf": 1613638734,
      "exp": 1613642634,
      "aio": "AVQAq/8TAAAA2GRwia3aJdRHuLybqI0/D8Vts36/cYj5AXp232Gp4DskwYzRlQ0ssN13qovqDODAUZv+CwozLJzwINbRzfRlR8VEJCT6ShTPPHF4eTNuqyY=",
      "hasgroups": "true",
      "name": "abc (EXT)",
      "nonce": "0da36184-4222-4816-b295-ed506d4f8e3c",
      "oid": "41527112-ccae-4978-9858-b3f120a0cd07",
      "preferred_username": "abc.com",
      "rh": "0.ARAAZCy4K7Eu90OIYv3B0jM7UAS5w6lsMu5LvWuW-sdNjt4QAGk.",
      "sub": "TCmqF1NyPUDsblQkqYlsNKKMuDf1LpOBvfO-ecTinwM",
      "tid": "2bb82c64-2eb1-43f7-8862-fdc1d2333b50",
      "upn": "abc.com",
      "uti": "VVXzO-Q1tEyQ2rlct1TaAA",
      "ver": "2.0"
    },
```

Comment: This can happen with groups; the user has too many of them to include them in the token. Check the docs for the options on group claims: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes. You might want to set it to only include groups assigned to the application and assign them. (this is a paid feature though) Otherwise, you might want to consider using app roles instead, or fetching groups from MS Graph API.

Comment: @juunas, I tried most of the options from this page..but no help :(
thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution,
go to Enterprise application option, find your app and click user & group inside your app portal. If you see any group assigned there then OK otherwise add group to it.
Now go to Azure AD -> App Registration -> application -> token config -> add a group claim,
click on Group Assigned to this app , sAMAccountName (for token)
..
GO to manifest and set

```
 "groupMembershipClaims": "ApplicationGroup",
```

### now fetch JWT-TOken, you will see a group array in your jwt-toke.

If you account is in sync with AD Connect, you'll see group name otherwise group id